# Expand using nodeId to the desired node in material ui TreeView when tree view reload

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I'm trying to reload the tree view with desired expanded nodes. In this example when treeView reloads it should be expanded to `nodeId 9` and only expands the parent of  `nodeId 9`. should not expand all nodes.

```
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setExpanded(["1"])
  },[])

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications"    
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents"
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain tree to be expanded by default, you can use **defaultExpanded** prop of **TreeView** component. An update of your code, that shows Node ID 9 and expands all its parents only, by default.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TreeView from '@mui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@mui/lab/TreeItem';
// import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  // const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setExpanded(["1"])
  // },[])

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={['5','6','7']}
      // expanded={expanded}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications"    
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents"
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

For more information about **defaultExpanded** prop and **TreeView** component, please visit the following link:
https://mui.com/api/tree-view/